# z-index issue for top nav of Stack exchange

Tags: bug, stackexchange

In stack-exchange - When we click on next privilege section of our profile and scroll little bit, the tool-tip overlaps the top navigation for all the browsers as below.

[image]

[image]

It's not a major CSS issue but it may be affecting other sections with same tool-tip, too.
This can be solved by increasing the z-index as below.

```
.top-bar { z-index: 9999; }
```

Comment: Nice observations